# How to Add Links in CheckBox's text in android?

Tags: android

I am making a registration form where i need a check box for agreeing term and condition. So problem is check box's text contains link to open web page(See image below). I am wondering if i can make check box clickable like `TextView` using `ClickableSpan`.

[image]

I have done this so far using below code:

Following method takes string and returns `SpannableString` that i set to checkbox.

```
private SpannableString makeSpannable(String text)
{
String temp = text;
Pattern pattern = Pattern
    .compile("<a href=[\\\"']([\\.^>^<\\w:/]*)[\\\"']>([^>^<.]*)</a>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find())
{
    temp = temp.replace(matcher.group(0), (matcher.group(2)));
}

SpannableString linkedString = new SpannableString(temp);
matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find())
{

    final String href = matcher.group(1);

    int index = temp.indexOf(matcher.group(2));
    ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget)
    {
        loadLink(href);
    }
    };
    linkedString.setSpan(clickable, index, index
        + matcher.group(2).length(), 0);
}
return linkedString;
}
```

> t.setText(makeSpannable(`"Ich akzeptiere die <a href='http://www.google.com'>AGB's</a> und <a href='http://www.google.com'>Datenschutzerklärung</a> des Verlags"`));

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: yes, i managed to do it with textview using ClickableSpan as mentioned in question.

Comment: I replaced `loadLink(href)` with `Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(href)); startActivity(browserIntent);` and none of those were clickable. So not working :(

Comment: Does text you want to make clickable tern blue like above exmple?

Comment: @chandil03 No it does not. The whole line is same format.

Comment: It means regx is not being applied to given text. can you post the text that you are passing to `makeSpannable()` method?